# install entityframework Error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I tried to install entityframework from nuget and PM but install stops halfway always.

I get problem with connection and the error is like this

```
Install-Package : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly close
d by the remote host.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Ok with my mind reading hat on - I think you have a problem. Seriously though - how do you expect people to help if you're not even trying to put any detail in the question?

Comment: i have edited the question also

Comment: Not sure why the error, but maybe you can do the install without using NuGet?

Comment: I tried to download the zip of the version 4.3 but when i tried to install It was with .nuget extension. I tried to install it but I could not feature out how to do that. Nuget manager does not show location to install already downloaded package

Comment: You can download them from http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/<PACKAGE_YOU_WANT>/ using your browser.

You can get the package name from: http://packages.nuget.org/Packages

Example: jQuery UI (Combined Library) Package is at: http://packages.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined To download: http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/jQuery.UI.Combined/

Answer (score 0):

Take .zip file for the package by downloading the package as 
packages.nuget.org/v1/package/download/AjaxControlToolkit

you can use v2 also in place of v1

then

make a folder D:\BackupNew and copy that AjaxControlToolkit.zip in that folder. This is nuget package but it have extension zip. So open it in zip and save as AjaxControlToolkit.nupkg.

Now it is nuget package to which nuget package manager can recognize easily.

Now add a Package source to Package manager from options of visual studio.

with name as LocalREPO and source url as D:\BackupNew

then open nuget package manager and  click on the local nuget package source and install that package from local computer ... finished